# Programmatic data binding in WPF not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working with two subclasses of `FrameworkElement` and trying to bind their widths and heights, so that when I set the `Width` or `Height` of one of the elements it updates the other element as well.  Yet I'm setting something incorrectly with the bindings, as when I use Visual Studio's WPF *Live Visual Tree* to see the properties of the two `FrameworkElements`, I see that one has its `Width` and `Height` set correctly, while the other's is set to `NAN`.  The code and snippets demonstrating the problem are below. What am I doing wrong?

**Binding Source**

[image: Binding Source]

**Binding Target**

[image: Binding Target]

**Code to create binding**

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.ChartView;

namespace CustomYAxis
{

    public class ChartYAxisAnnotation : CartesianCustomAnnotation
    {
        private readonly CustomYAxisView _annotationContent;

        public ChartYAxisAnnotation()
        {
            Content = _annotationContent = new CustomYAxisView();

            // These bindings aren't working
            var widthBinding = new Binding(nameof(WidthProperty))
            {
                Source = this,
            };

            var heightBinding = new Binding(nameof(HeightProperty))
            {
                Source = this
            };

            _annotationContent.SetBinding(WidthProperty, widthBinding);
            _annotationContent.SetBinding(HeightProperty, heightBinding);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just for debugging sake, have you tried adding a bogus converter just to see if you pass through it. Also have you tried setting Mode = TwoWay, just to see if anything changes

Comment: Also I would use WidthProperty.Name instead of nameof(WidthProperty)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I just tried both things.  The values _do not_ pass through the bogus converter, and setting the Mode to TwoWay doesn't change anything.

Comment: Changing WidthProperty.Name _does_ cause the values to pass through the bogus converter.  But, the value is `NAN`.  I'm editing my question to show how I'm setting the `Width` and `Height` on the first framework element.

Comment: Actually, changing the name to WidthProperty.Name was it! Thanks so much!  If you want to add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameof(WidthProperty)` actually returns "WidthProperty"

what you want to do is bind the property which name is "Width", same goes for HeightProperty

Therefore you should change `nameof(WidthProperty)` to `WidthProperty.Name` or `"Width"`